# Looking for case-insensitive in Phalcon Datatables Library (m1ome)

Tags: datatable, phalcon

I use this Library : 
https://github.com/m1ome/phalcon-datatables

This is how i use it :

```
        $resultset = $this->modelsManager
            ->createQuery("SELECT protId, protUsmsName, protUsmsId, protComsName,  protAddress, protQty, protPrice, protTotalPrice, 
                          protShpmName,  protDateOrder , protPthdId
                            FROM ProductOrderTransaction WHERE AuditDelete = 'N' AND protMomsId = '4' 
                            ORDER BY protId DESC")
            ->execute();
        $dataTables = new DataTable();
        $dataTables->fromResultSet($resultset)->sendResponse();
```

But, while i  search "company" in the Data tables, it can't be found because it has value "Company". Case sensitive case.

Anyone had the modify Lib? thx

Comment: was done.

i just modified it thx

Answer (score 0):

```
          $check = (strpos(strtoupper( $item->$column ), strtoupper(  $search ) ) !== false);
```